# Firebase app check not working with React Native + iOS 16 App Attest

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check

I have been trying to get Firebase App Check to work for months and still no luck.

I am currently testing on iOS 16.2.

I have followed all of these steps and am at a loss:

1. Add the App Check package using yarn add @react-native-firebase/app-check
2. Configure and initialize App Check
3. Created a Key in Apple Developer Console with DeviceCheck and App Attest.
4. Enabled DeviceCheck in Firebase console Project settings with Key ID and Team ID
5. Added App Attest and Device Check in the Firebase console.
6. Set .entitlements App Attest to production.
7. Enforced Cloud Storage and Firestore to use App Check.
8. In my main app target, I added the capability for App Attest in Xcode Signing & Capabilities

I keep getting: Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions, when enforcing App Check

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Yes it ended up being that I was still using the firebase-js-sdk for getting the documents I needed. Once I started using @react-native-firebase/app
to get all of my documents, everything worked perfectly!